# Question about Munkres' proof that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is isomorphic to the integers

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have one quick question about the proof that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}$. I think that I understand the proof, but there is just one detail that I wanna clarify. At some point, Munkres wrote that:

> Given $[f]$ and $[g]$ in $\pi_1(B, b0)$, let $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ be their respective liftings to paths on $\mathbb{R}$ beginning at $0$.

The thing that causes me some problem is that Munkres seems to state that there is one lifting to  path on $\mathbb{R}$ for each path-homotopy equivalence class. However, I thought that there was a lifting to path for each $f$ of $[f]$, but that they were all homotopic, i.e. $[\tilde{f}]$ is the path-homotopy equivalence class containing each of the lifting to path of elements of $[f]$. So my question is, is there one unique lifting to path beginning at one defined point for each path-homotopy equivalence class ?
In the context of the proof, this is not really important because what matters is the end of the lifting to paths.
Thanks !

Comment: The lift becomes unique once one specifies a beginning point "upstairs". He explicitly says "... *beginning at 0*".

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I also read that in the book, but I thought that this statement was true for a determined $f$ of $[f]$, not for the entire path-homoopy class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u, v : X \to S^1$ be maps having lifts $\tilde u, \tilde v : X\to \mathbb R$. Of course a neccessary condition for $\tilde u = \tilde v$ is $u = v$.

Thus there does not exist a common lift for all representatives of an element of $\pi_1(S^1,b_0)$. I therefore think that Munkres' formulation is a bit misleading. Actually he considers $a, b \in  \pi_1(S^1,b_0)$, chooses representatives $f \in a$ and $g \in b$ and lifts them to paths $\tilde f, \tilde g$ both beginning at $0$. For his further considerations only the endpoints of $\tilde f, \tilde g$ are relevant, and these only depend on the path homotopy classes $a, b$. The purpose of the paths $\tilde f, \tilde g$ is to find a lift of the product path $f * g$ which represents $a * b$.

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure, because usually Munkres is pretty neat with his proofs